# Where can I find maps of buses / bus routes in Muscat?

Tags: buses, routes, maps, muscat

Having visited Muscat at the beginning of February 2017 and not currently driving, I attempted to travel around the Muscat area by its bus network - Mwasalat. (FYI, visiting Muscat without a car is challenging to say the least!)

The problem is that it's not easy to find your way around with little information provided - the best indication [are the website timetables](http://mwasalat.om/en-us/Bus-routes/Time-Table), which incidentally doesn't work on mobile and don't list the route numbers. There's not even a map of the network on their website or even at the bus station in Ruwi.

As far as I know:

- Route 1 runs from Ruwi into Muscat center.
- Route 4 runs from Ruwi to Mutrah and Al-Alam Palace.

Anyone have other information about all the routes available?

Comment: @pnuts I think I might just do that - Whilst I've long since returned from Muscat, this would be useful for anyone else, so I'll share what I find.

Comment: The only bus map I found in Muscat was for the [Big Bus](https://www.bigbustours.com/en/muscat/muscat-routes-and-tour-maps/)…

Answer (score 4):

http://www.opencyclemap.org/?zoom=15&lat=51.522&lon=-0.22775&layers=0B

OpenStreetMap has *some* bus stops in Muscat, too few to use it to navigate but enough to understand the extent reachable by bus.

I understand that you don't want to drive there, but how about taking a cab/taxi? They're usually plentiful in developing countries and not that expensive, provided that you don't get conned.

Answer (score 3):

Well, mwasalat introduced an interactive map last year and sad to hear that you didn't knew it.

http://www.mwasalat.om/l/en.html
This is a responsive page which use google map to show you the routes, stations =, etc. You can access it via mobile too.  The station names listed in side is clickable and it show the particular point on the map with an effect

Comment: I can't see any routes there, only a list of bus stations. However Google shows bus stops on the map, maybe they have routes too?

Comment: In the right, a list of stations are there, in that, you can see a link _mwasalat.com/intercity_ clicking on it will bring you all the routes.

Comment: I think that OP asked about local routes and not intercity.